# Repeated Timer on Windows and Cygwin with (1) ms Accuracy

Tags: c++, multithreading, posix, freertos

I have a problem calling a function every millisecond in my C++ program.

I have an embedded project running FreeRTOS of which I want to run parts on my local machine. For that I am using a FreeRTOS simulator that is built on top of Posix threads. FreeRTOS internally relies on an interrupt calling a tick handler every millisecond (or other configurable interval). The simulator uses itimers (setitimer) to generate a signal at a regular interval and sigaction to attach a handler to the signal. But then I realized that the tick handler is called much less than every millisecond. After simplifying the program again and again I realized that even this snippet

```
std::thread t([]() {
    int i = 0;
    while (true) {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::microseconds(1000));
        if ((i++ % 100) == 0)
            printf("tick\n");
    }
});
t.detach();

while(true) {}
```

prints *tick* much less than you would expect it to.
I know that sleep functions usually do not guarantee waking just after expiration of the interval and significant overhead can lead to delays much more noticeable with shorter sleep times.
What I'm looking for is a pragmatic solution to simulate the systick timer of the RTOS with agreeable accuracy.

My platform is Cygwin on Windows 10, by the way. Could be that the itimer implementation on Linux distributions is better.

Comment: Not at all - Hard real-time operating systems are better at real-time that non-real time OSs. If you tried Ubuntu, which is *not* realtime, you'd get problems too. If you run you program at low priority it will get a less accurate timer than processes running at high priority.

Comment: Windows *can* handle soft-real time and multimedia jobs (which require far more than 1ms accuracy) through the [multimedia class scheduler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/multimedia-class-scheduler-service?redirectedfrom=MSDN) and its real-time work queues. Without it, Windows wouldn't be able to handle games, video and audio without stutter. That's still soft real-time though.

Comment: You can configure the general timer to run more frequently, but that results in far higher power consumption. That's what Chrome does and why everyone hates it

Comment: Interrupts are as far as possible to get from user threads in any OS though. Thread scheduling means your process can be interrupted at any moment without any of when it will come back. You can't get the same accuracy with an emulator on a non-RT OS you'd get with an RT system. I'm pretty sure many people have already built RT *and* RT systems though. I know Windows is used for soft-RT systems since the 00s. They did it either with an emulated clock or by using special schedulers, perhaps even custom drivers to *avoid* thread scheduling, priority boosting etc

Comment: [Relevant](https://sourceware.org/legacy-ml/cygwin-developers/2005-11/msg00000.html), not obvious what actually happened.